# How can a table be rearranged one step at a time so that two or more observations are listed in a row in successive columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

So far I have done this to achieve the desired result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
   frag treat
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     1
3     1     2
4     2     2

treat_1 <- tab_example %>% filter(treat == "1")
treat_2 <- tab_example %>% filter(treat == "2")

new_tab_example <- full_join(treat_1, treat_2, by = "frag")

> new_tab_example
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   frag treat.x treat.y
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1       1       2
2     2       1       2
```

Is there a way to do it in one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` :

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(tab_example, names_from = treat, 
                   names_prefix = 'treat', values_from = treat)

#   frag treat1 treat2
#  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1      1      2
#2     2      1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way using [spread()](https://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/) function:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 

# Yours data 
df = tibble(frag = c(1, 2, 1, 2), treat = c(1,1,2,2) )


dfnew = df %>%
  mutate(treat_name = case_when(treat==1 ~ 'treat.x', # Build names of columns
                                treat==2 ~ 'treat.y')
         ) %>%
  spread(treat_name, treat) # Use spread function
```

If you print the result:

```
print(dfnew)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
   frag treat.x treat.y
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1       1       2
2     2       1       2
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work when the table has additional columns with data.
All data that belongs to a specific frag should be in one row like this:
`# A tibble: 2 x 7
   frag treat.x obs_1.x obs_2.x treat.y obs_1.y obs_2.y
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  
1     1       1     0.9 yes           2     1.2 yes    
2     2       1     0.8 no            2     1.3 yes    `

Comment: I understand, can you provide a full example of your data then? It's important that the question is an reproducible example of exactly what you want.